# M2.2 Recently view products remove Learn More Link

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, recently-viewed

I have created a `Recently Viewed Products` widget and in the widget option I can select what is shown for every product, attributes and buttons.

In the attributes there is an option of a *Learn More Link* which is not selected. However in the Recently viewed products, there is a Learn More link.

How could I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the following file:

> vendor/magento/module-reports/view/frontend/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_list.phtml

You will find the following code:

```
$description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false;
```

also check the following code which renders the **Learn more** link:

```
<?php if ($description):?>
    <div class="product-item-description">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
        <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"
           href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>"
           class="action more"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Learn More') ?></a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which means on list mode learn more always visible. You need to change the logic there but copy the file to your theme location like below:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Reports/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_list.phtml

Comment: `List mode` you mean how the products are viewed? The options were `Grid` and `List` which I used both , with `Learn more link` un-selected.  And the link was visible both time. If I delete that `<a>` with the *Learn more* string,  would I be ok?

Comment: There are 2 types of view in magento one is list view and another one is grid view. Learn more button always shows for list view. you can either change the line $description = ($mode == 'list') ? false : false; to false : false for both then Learn more button will be removed for both views Or you can remove it from the code.

Comment: Is it working fine?

Comment: I want to use grid view for this purpose. However there is no mention of grid in the `viewed_list.phtml` file. Should I add code about grid view? Or delete the *Learn more* link all together?

Comment: Yes because there is a file in the same path called viewed_grid.phtml which is used for grid view. You can delete that link from code.

Comment: Oh silly me :P. I will check it out asap and come back. Ty

Comment: I will accept it. Ty

Comment: in the `viewed_grid.phtml` there is no *Learn more* link.

Comment: Also in the `viewed_grid.phtml` there is this weird line: `$description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false;`

Comment: In viewed_grid.phtml there is no such links are there because if you check product listing page there is no such links are available in grid view and if you switch it to list view then you will see Learn more link. Basically grid view not contains any learn more link.

Comment: For this weird line Also in the viewed_grid.phtml there is this weird line: $description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false; you can change the true to false then Learn more link will not show in your page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80025/discussion-between-superdeveloper-and-sukumar-gorai).